# Convert two array from different function in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm parsing a website with two functions: `href_link` and `get_price`. Each of them adds the value on its own array.

After I call the function `get_hash` on both functions in order to convert the array to a  hash.

Where is my mistake in the function `get_hash` because I get an error executing the script:

```
:68:in `zip': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Here is my code

```
def get_hash(*arr)
  h = Hash[arr[0].zip arr[1]]
  puts h
end


def href_link
  page.css("div#main div#center div#center-middle .content .listing-torrent table td a").each do |link|
href = link["href"]
  array_href = []
   array_href << href
    get_hash(array_href)
  end
end

def get_price
 array = []
    page.css("div#main div#center div#center-middle .content .listing-torrent table tbody tr td p").each do |price|
      array << price
     get_hash(array)
   end
end
```

Comment: change this `get_hash(array_href)` to `get_hash(*array_href)` or change `def get_hash(*arr)` to `def get_hash(arr)`

Comment: it looks like the error is happening because one of the arrays is empty?

Comment: Apart from the fact that your code formatting is a disaster here, with indentation anything but consistent, you need to check out your full stack trace to see where this originates.

Comment: if i do what you say @bjhaid it's almost good . the last problem  is  i get the same value in key and in value exemple: hash : {" 12"=>" 12"

Comment: what i try to get is    hash : {" price"=>" href"}

Comment: do  you have an idea how can do that ?